# Java hanging on FileOutputStream.close() for S3-to-EC2 Download

Tags: java, linux, amazon-s3

I have an application that's hanging on `FileOutputStream.close()` (well, really it's hanging on the native `FileOutputStream.close0()` but whatever). And... I don't really know what would cause that. How would an expert at Java/Linux debugging approach this problem?

I've used `jstack` to find the crime scene, and here it is:

```
s3-transfer-manager-worker-1" #22 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f9f40007800 nid=0x2e6 runnable [0x00007f9fac4d7000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.close0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.access$000(FileOutputStream.java:53)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream$1.close(FileOutputStream.java:356)
        at java.io.FileDescriptor.closeAll(FileDescriptor.java:212)
        - locked <0x00000005c3bbc440> (a java.io.FileDescriptor)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.close(FileOutputStream.java:354)
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.implCloseChannel(FileChannelImpl.java:139)
        at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.close(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:115)
        - locked <0x00000005c3bbc600> (a java.lang.Object)
        at com.amazonaws.util.IOUtils.closeQuietly(IOUtils.java:70)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.ServiceUtils.appendFile(ServiceUtils.java:473)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.CompleteMultipartDownload.call(CompleteMultipartDownload.java:46)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.CompleteMultipartDownload.call(CompleteMultipartDownload.java:29)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

#### Download Code

Here's a simplified version of our S3 download code:

```
AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain());
s3Client.setRegion(...);
TransferManager s3TransferManager = TransferManagerBuilder.standard().withS3Client(s3Client).build();

GetObjectRequest objectRequest = new GetObjectRequest(...);
Path localTempFile = Files.createTempFile(...);
Download downloadHandle = s33TransferManager.download(objectRequest, localTempFile.toFile());

downloadHandle.waitForCompletion();
```

Pretty vanilla.

#### Background

This is a pretty vanilla usage of the Java AWS S3 API to download a file to the local disk. I can download the same file using the `aws s3 cp ...` command line application just fine. Even more confusingly, the application was working just fine previously. It has about 1000 of these files to download, and it made it through 11 of them before this started happening.

Things I know:

- These are beefy files, about 20 GB each.
- I've tried multiple times, and let it sit there for 1:00h and lately, for 2:00h. It stays hung.
- We have plenty of free disk space: 200 GB. (And it'd be throwing an exception if that were the problem, anyways.)
- I tried turning it off and then on again (via `sudo reboot`).
- It's an `m4.2xlarge` EC2 instance.
- Per CloudWatch, the CPU isn't busy.
- I can download the exact same file from S3 to the exact same location via the `aws s3 cp ...` command line, which rules out:

  - Disk space problems (again).
  - IOPS shortages (unless the Java SDK's `TransferManager` is doing something really different and dumb).
  - Really slow downloads: it only takes about 5 minutes to download the file on the command line.
  - File permission problems.

#### Next Steps?

Unfortunately, I don't know enough to go any further than that in debugging this. Are there specific Linux metrics or commands I should be checking to see if some system resource has been exhausted or deadlocked?

Comment: does the issue persist when file is relatively smaller, let's say like 2-5 GB. what is the main memory size ? did you see the main memory graph during upload or just after exception occurred ? also how does your transfer manger client code looks like

Comment: Not very familiar with that API but AFAIK it is asynchronous. So, what's about polling the status actively and look what it says?
BTW: 200 GB is not much, if you try to download more than 11 files with 20 GB each. Apparently it will not be enough if you keep the files on disk

Comment: It's an `m4.2xlarge` box running just this, so it's got a 24GB max heap. We clean up the files after each is downloaded and processed, so we're fine on disk space.

Answer (score 0):

I almost hate to say this, because it's every coder's favorite stalking horse, but "it was the commercial security software." When we disabled the scanning process, it magically fixed itself.

Turns out, it wasn't completely hanging, it was just assembling all of the downloaded `.part` files incredibly slowly: one 8MB chunk every 40 seconds. I guess the security process was intercepting the file writes and tangling them up somehow? I dunno'.